# "Visual Basic 2015" convert Ascii to Characters fails why

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, ascii, implicit-conversion

I am doing the following conversion from Numeric Ascii values to their respective characters in Visual Basic but it fails miserably:

Here the value given in pth has already been converted to Ascii values so what you see in the variable textval variable is the ascii equivalint of the path

```
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim dec As String
    Dim original As Integer
    Dim sentence As String
    Dim inter As String
    Dim pth =" c:\TESTER:\JESTER\MESTER "
    textval="32 99 58 92 84 69 83 84 69 82 58 92 74 69 83 84 69 82 92 77 69 83 84 69 82 32"
    textval = Trim(textval)
    'Dim ts() As String = Split(textval)
    Dim words As String() = textval.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    Label1.Text = words(0) + words(1) + words(2)
    original = Int(ts(2))
```

the above code does not give any value for words(2) the second character which is a COLON ":" or for the ascii number 2961

How Can I correct this problem and make this more universal to take any special characters as well?

Thanks in advance for your valuable answers.

Comment: You are not doing any conversion here. You are simply splitting a string at spaces.

Comment: You need `Chr` to convert from int to character.

Comment: Pls check recent edit..

Comment: which line convert from int to character? you simply output numbers on textfield.

Comment: Yes that is a value which I read from the file the Integers come from a file which is has ascii equivalent of the value in **PTH variable** It is not being converted in this program. @SebastianBrosch

Comment: original = Int(ts(2)) This is the line where the conversion happens @SebastianBrosch

Comment: @PuneetMathur - that lines location doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't convert the integer value to a character. You have to use [`Chr` or `ChrW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46(v=vs.90).aspx) to solve this. See the following code example:

**solution using `Chr`:**

```
Dim textValues1 As String = "32 99 58 92 84 69 83 84 69 82 58 92 74 69 83 84 69 82 92 77 69 83 84 69 82 32"
textValues1 = textValues1.Trim
Dim textWords1 As String() = textValues1.Split(New Char() {" "c})
Dim strValue1 As String = ""

For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(textWords1)
    Dim numValue As Integer = 0

    If Integer.TryParse(textWords1(i), numValue) Then
        strValue1 &= Chr(CInt(numValue))
    End If
Next

Debug.Print(strValue1) 'output:  c:\TESTER:\JESTER\MESTER
```

**solution using `ChrW`:**

```
Dim textValues2 As String = "32 99 58 92 84 69 83 84 69 82 58 92 74 69 83 84 69 82 92 77 69 83 84 69 82 32"
textValues2 = textValues2.Trim
Dim textWords2() As String = textValues2.Split(New Char() {" "c})
Dim strValue2 As String = ""

For j As Integer = 0 To UBound(textWords2)
    Dim numValue As Integer = 0

    If Integer.TryParse(textWords2(j), numValue) Then
        strValue2 &= ChrW(CInt(numValue))
    End If
Next

Debug.Print(strValue2) 'output: c:\TESTER:\JESTER\MESTER
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the input is invalid.

Comment: I don't understand why this genuine question is being downgraded when the Answer is so perfectly was given by @SebastianBrosch Many Thanks for your answer this works 100%  Please somebody upvote this question instead of the -2

Comment: I like your solution @Sebastian Brosch both are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This code should give you ideas.  Note that the string values of integer representations are verified to be integers before they are converted.

```
    Dim textval As String = "32 a 99 58 92 84 69 83 84 69 82 58 92 74 69 83 84 69 82 92 77 69 83 84 69 82 32"
    Dim cvals As New List(Of Char)

    For Each s As String In textval.Split(New Char() {" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim ival As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(s, ival) Then
            cvals.Add(ChrW(ival))
        End If
    Next

    Dim cv As String = cvals.ToArray ' c:\TESTER:\JESTER\MESTER
```

This method verifies that the input is valid.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a generic "Visual studio 2015" answer then use the existing functionality of the .Net Framework. Consider the following statements to convert a string to bytes or chars:

```
Dim bytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pth)
Dim chars = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytes)
Dim stringValue = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
```

You can use other encodings as well, like UTF8 and Unicode, if special characters are involved. Here's a link to the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.asciiencoding(v=vs.110).aspx